# How can i handle JSON object while some values are not even nil (missing or not exist) for swift

Tags: json, swift

Hello everyone i have an json object with problem of irregularly response, sometimes it not sending some of the both keys and values  my model like:

```
struct GetComments: Codable {
   let name, surname: String
   let photoPath: String
   let commentid, comment, date: String
   let commentOwner: String
   let id : String
   let email: String
}
```

i have tried giving some initial value for model like below, but it still crashes:

```
struct GetComments: Codable {
   let name, surname: String = “”
   let photoPath: String = “”
   let commentid, comment, date: String = “”
   let commentOwner: String = “”
   let id : String = “”
   let email: String = “”
}
```

full of my json object like:

```
{
   “name”:"Calvin",
   “surname”:“Harris”,
   “photoPath”: "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/181/181549.png",
   “commentid”: “ASHF579OTUJKDH475870987NBMVK”,
   “comment”: “hello everyone”,
   “date”: “11/06/2019",
   “commentOwner”: “Calvin Harris”,
   “id”: “LHKHOYIYU9OTUJKDH475870987NBMVK”,
   “email”: “calvin@test.com”
}
```

and problem starts when i received it like:

```
{
       “name”:“Calvin”,
       “surname”:“Harris”,
       “commentid”: “ASHF579OTUJKDH475870987NBMVK”,
       “comment”: “hello everyone”,
       “date”: “11/06/2019",
       “commentOwner”: “Calvin Harris”,
       “id”: “LHKHOYIYU9OTUJKDH475870987NBMVK”,
    }
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In your case you should use container and while giving initial values for your model you define them as constant they should be variable. To use your model with container:

```
struct GetComments: Codable {
    let name, surname: String?
    let photoPath: String?
    let commentid, comment, date: String?
    let commentOwner: String?
    let id : String?
    let email: String?

    init (from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.name = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name) ?? ""
        self.surname = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .surname) ?? ""
        self.photoPath = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .photoPath) ??  "maybe a place holder url or empty string"
        self.commentid = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .commentid) ?? ""
        self.comment = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .comment) ?? ""
        self.date = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .date) ?? ""
        self.commentOwner = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .commentOwner) ?? ""
        self.email = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .email) ?? ""
        self.id = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .id) ?? ""
    }

}
```

I hope this would solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

Just declare the struct members as optional which can be `nil`

```
struct GetComments: Codable {
   let name, surname: String
   let photoPath: String? // can also be decoded as URL?
   let commentid, comment, date: String
   let commentOwner: String
   let id : String
   let email: String?
}
```

Comment: No, then the corresponding members just remain `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

**Use optional operator**

Your structure should be like:

```
struct GetComments: Codable {
   var name: String?
   var surname: String?
   var photoPath: String?
   var commentid: String?
   var comment: String?
   var date: String?
   var commentOwner: String?
   var id : String?
   var email: String?

   // method actually defines the key
   enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case name // = " your actual key name"
       case surname
       case last_name
   }

   // methods actually parsing the data
   required public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
       let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

       name  = try values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .name)
       surname = try values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .surname)

     // rest of the parsing data

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **optional values** for the ones you won't always receive and in your `required init(from decoder: Decoder)` use `decodeIfPresent` for the optional values

```
required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        photoPath = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .photoPath)
}
```